# Markup of a blog page and its posts

Tags: html, html5

Currently building my personal site using Jekyll, inuitcss and GitHub Pages. I'd like to hear your thoughts on the markup of my blog page and its post pages.

What do you think about handling logo's like this? Also I'm not sure about the headings. The page-title probably should be part of the main section.

**blog markup:**

```
<body>
    <header class=site-head role=banner>
        <a href="/" class=site-logo>
            <!-- base64 encoded transparent gif; logo is applied through background-image -->
            <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" alt="site-title">
        </a>

        <nav class=site-nav role=navigation>
            <a href="/" class=nav__item--blog rel=home>Blog</a><!--
         --><a href="/portfolio" class=nav__item--portfolio>Portfolio</a><!--
         --><a href="/profil" class=nav__item--profil>Profil</a><!--
         --><a href="/impressum" class=nav__item--impressum>Impressum</a>
        </nav>

        <h1 class=page-title>Freundliche Artikel</h1>
    </header>

    <main class="page-content wrapper" role=main>
        <ul class=post-list>
            <li>
                <a href="/2014/01/one-nice-little-article" class=post-list__link>
                    <span class=post-list__time>26. Januar 2014</span>
                    <h2 class=post-list__title>We can't stop here</h2>
                </a>
                <p>This is a post excerpt from the actual article. Usually the first paragraph.</p>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/2014/01/sweet-introduction" class=post-list__link>
                    <span class=post-list__time>15. Januar 2014</span>
                    <h2 class=post-list__title>Introduction anyone?</h2>
                </a>
                <p>This is a post excerpt from the actual article. Usually the first paragraph.</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </main>

    <footer class=site-foot role=contentinfo>
        <p>Author. Hosting. Used tools.</p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

**post markup:**

```
<body>
    <header class=site-head role=banner>
        <a href="/" class=site-logo>
            <!-- base64 encoded transparent gif; logo is applied through background-image -->
            <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" alt="site-title">
        </a>

        <nav class=site-nav role=navigation>
            <a href="/" class=nav__item--blog rel=home>Blog</a><!--
         --><a href="/portfolio" class=nav__item--portfolio>Portfolio</a><!--
         --><a href="/profil" class=nav__item--profil>Profil</a><!--
         --><a href="/impressum" class=nav__item--impressum>Impressum</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main class="page-content wrapper" role=main>
        <article class=entry>
            <span class=entry__meta>26. Januar 2014</span>
            <h1>We can't stop here&hellip;</h1>

            <p>How're you doing? Eveything alright?</p>

            <p>Another paragraph. Might be a conclusion.</p>
        </article>
    </main>

    <footer class=site-foot role=contentinfo>
        <p>Author. Hosting. Used tools.</p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Blog markup

The site title should be a `h1`.

Use an `ul` for the navigation links. Or, if you don’t want that, use at least a `div` element for each link, or a textual separator between each link.

The page title (+ the content under its scope) needs be enclosed in a sectioning element (probably `section` in this case). Also, don’t include the page title in the site’s `header`.

The `main` element should also contain the page title.

Each post excerpt should get its own `article` (as a general rule: don’t use headings in list items (e.g. `li`) unless they have a sectioning content parent).

You may use the `time` element for the dates.

Which leads to (excluding anything not related to the outline):

```
<body>

  <header>

    <h1><img src="" alt="…"></h1>

    <nav></nav>

  </header>

  <main>
  <section>

    <h1>Freundliche Artikel</h1>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <article>
          <h2>We can't stop here</h2>
        </article>
      </li>
      <li>
        <article>
          <h2>Introduction anyone?</h2>
        </article>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </section>
  </main>

  <footer></footer>

</body>
```

#### Post markup

Again, use the site heading as `h1` (as a child of body, without any sectioning content element parents).

Again, use `ul` for the navigation links etc.

You may use the `time` element for the dates.

Your `footer` contains information about the whole page (`body`). So if one of the articles is written by a different author, the `article` should get its own `footer`.

---

Some further explanations from the comments:

#### (a) Why the site name should be `body`s `h1`

Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14920215/1591669) to a different question. The last example (HTML + the corresponding outline) applies to your case.

In short: When you don’t use a heading for the site name, your main content heading will be used as the heading for the whole `body`. Everything else on this page will be in scope of this heading. But there are things on your page which shouldn’t be in its scope, for example your navigation.

In your current HTML, the `nav` (which clearly represents navigation for the whole *site*) would be in the scope of "Freundliche Artikel" (while your `nav` might be friendly, it’s clearly not an article ;-)).

#### (b) Why the logo can be used for (a)

(You need to agree with (a) first.)

Headings are not for text only. A logo typically represents the site name (blog name, company name, whatever). It doesn’t matter if the logo includes a textual representation or if it’s graphics only. In both cases, the `alt` text would be the textual site name, as this is what the logo stands for.

#### (c) Why you can’t use sectioning elements (for your main content) when your main content is not included in a sectioning element and you have a site heading

Let’s take this (wrong) example:

```
<h1>Artikelschmiede <!-- site name --></h1>

<h2>Freundliche Artikel <!-- main content heading --></h2>

<article>
  <h3>We can't stop here</h3>
</article>

<article>
  <h3>Introduction anyone?</h3>
</article>
```

The outline is:

```
1. Artikelschmiede
  1.1 Freundliche Artikel
  1.2 We can't stop here
  1.3 Introduction anyone?
```

But the outline should be:

```
1. Artikelschmiede
  1.1 Freundliche Artikel
    2.1 We can't stop here
    2.2 Introduction anyone?
```

So to get the correct outline, use a sectioning element for the whole main content (typically `section` or `article`):

```
<h1>Artikelschmiede <!-- site name --></h1>

<section>
  <h2>Freundliche Artikel <!-- main content heading --></h2>

  <article>
    <h3>We can't stop here</h3>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h3>Introduction anyone?</h3>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: 1. I disagree on using `h1` only for site-titles. I have a logo and no present site-title on the page. This makes the page-title on pages and the article titles in post-pages the highest heading in the hierarchy. 2. Isn't the whole page itself the scope for my page-title? The section element seperates sections of content (like of articles). I agree on moving it to the main element, tho. 3. Also using `article` for the post excerpts makes sense. (to be continued...)

Comment: 4. Using the `time` element there is a good idea. 5. Good point for the `footer` inside articles. However this is my personal site. There won't be other authors (for the time now. ;). 6. I'd like to hear a reason for using a list for my navigation.

Comment: @kleinfreund: 1. Headings don’t need to consist of text. And that aside, your `img` has `alt` content, which will get used as heading content for consumers not capable of parsing images (i.e., search engines). Without using the site name in the top-level heading, your document outline will be wrong!

Comment: @kleinfreund: 2. Yes, currently. But when you use the site name as top-level heading (or in other words: as heading for the `body` sectioning root element) [→ 1], then you’ll have to use a sectioning element for the main content (or you may use corresponding heading levels `h2`-`h6` but (!) then you can’t use sectioning content elements anymore on that page.

Comment: @kleinfreund: 6. -- a) First, why you should use block level elements (like `div` or `li`): in text browsers (i.e., browsers without CSS support), your links would be displayed all in one line, without any separators. So either use block level elements (then each link will be displayed on its own line) or use a textual separator (e.g., `·` or something like that). -- b) Why `ul`? Because your navigation consists of a *set* of links, e.g., it represents the sections of your site (you are communicating: "My site is divided into four sections", which gives a start/end for screenreaders).

Comment: 1. A logo is not a heading. I don't see how not using an actual site-title as the `h1` makes your document outline wrong. Sources? 2. Why can't I use sectioning elements on that page anymore when I use `h2`-`h6`? Maybe we should discuss this in a chat?

Comment: @kleinfreund: I added explanations to my answer.

Comment: In my opinion, using a heading for a logo is wrong and I keep it this way. I moved my page title to the `main` element, which makes my outline correct for now. You're right though, if I use a h1 as a site title, I will need to rework the outline. I also considered deliting the navigational elements with line-breaks (whitespace), but I switched to using an `ul` now. Btw I had no votes left yesterday and didn't remember today. I will upvote and accept tomorrow. ;)

Comment: @kleinfreund: Note that if you agree with (a), you could still get the correct ouline by using a sectioning element for the main content and omitting a heading for the `body`. My point is not (primarily) that the logo needs to be used as site heading, but that there needs to be a top-level entry in the outline. This can be achieved by using a heading (containing text, a graphic, an audio file …) or by using sectioning elements explicitly everywhere, so that no heading belongs to `body`.